# Getting empty result using Regular Expression function in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I am using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM xnwu4_shows WHERE show_name REGEXP '^(0-9)'
```

it gives a empty result but according to mysql mannual used function is correct and should be gives some result because my database table have type (Regular Expression, string started with a numeric value or any number) of data.

Give me any idea to resolve above problem

Comment: Please return to some of your earlier questions and mark answers accepted where appropriate and correct. You are more likely to get more and swifter help here in the future if you do.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `[]` instead of `()`

```
SELECT * FROM xnwu4_shows WHERE show_name REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

This assumes you are attempting to match a digit 0-9 at the beginning of the string, rather than the literal string `'0-9'`, which is what is being matched by `(0-9)` in parentheses.